# How to use sql union with joined query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, join

This is my first time in "stackoverflow". I am just starting my programming final project and having a problem with the sql query. (Sorry for my bad English also)

I have three tables called zstatistics,zsuggestions and ZEntrycriteria . I have a sql query that will "UNION" both zstatistics,zsuggestions and then order the results to match the closest result.

```
    select M.* 
          from zstatistics M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code
          where C.Maths <= @maths
            AND C.Science <= @science
            AND C.English <= @english
            And C.Ict <= @ict
            And C.History <= @history
            And C.Geography <= @geography
            And C.Art <= @Art

UNION 

        select M.* 
         from zsuggestions M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code 
         where C.Maths <= @maths 
           AND C.Science <= @science 
           AND C.English <= @english 
           And C.Ict <= @ict And C.History <= @history 
           And C.Geography <= @geography 
           And C.Art <= @Art  
ORDER BY 

      sqrt( power(M.Maths - @maths, 2) + power(M.Science - @science,2) + power(M.English - @english,2) + power(M.Ict - @ict,2) + power(M.History-@history,2) + power(M.Geography - @geography,2) + power(M.Art - @Art,2))
```

I also tried following

```
select * from
(
select M.* 
          from zstatistics M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code
          where C.Maths <= @maths
            AND C.Science <= @science
            AND C.English <= @english
            And C.Ict <= @ict
            And C.History <= @history
            And C.Geography <= @geography
            And C.Art <= @Art

UNION 

        select M.* 
         from zsuggestions M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code 
         where C.Maths <= @maths 
           AND C.Science <= @science 
           AND C.English <= @english 
           And C.Ict <= @ict And C.History <= @history 
           And C.Geography <= @geography 
           And C.Art <= @Art  
)
ORDER BY 

      sqrt( power(M.Maths - @maths, 2) + power(M.Science - @science,2) + power(M.English - @english,2) + power(M.Ict - @ict,2) + power(M.History-@history,2) + power(M.Geography - @geography,2) + power(M.Art - @Art,2))
```

But i am getting a syntax error saying "Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator."

Thank you  (edited)

Comment: Strongly suggest you get the query working before embedding it in an application.  Go back to Management Studio and run the query.  It will give you better error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `UNION`, just put it between you query. the final query would be like

```
select * from
(
select M.* 
  from zstatistics M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code
  where C.Maths <= @maths
    AND C.Science <= @science
    AND C.English <= @english
    And C.Ict <= @ict
    And C.History <= @history
    And C.Geography <= @geography
    And C.Art <= @Art

UNION

select M.* 
from zsuggestions M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code 
where C.Maths <= @maths
  AND C.Science <= @science
  AND C.English <= @english
  And C.Ict <= @ict
  And C.History <= @history
  And C.Geography <= @geography
  And C.Art <= @Art
  ) t

 ORDER BY sqrt( power(t.Maths - @maths, 2) + power(t.Science - @science,2) + power(t.English - @english,2) + power(t.Ict - @ict,2) + power(t.History-@history,2) + power(t.Geography - @geography,2) + power(t.Art - @Art,2))
```

as long as both query results have the same columns, then you can `UNION` both of the result like this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. By doing that gives me a syntax error "Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'."

Comment: @timton, that's because you cannot have `order by` before `union`. Remove that line (and you may need to rework the last `order by` line as well to get it working).

Comment: @ ZLK  thank you for the comment. Could you please tell me what u mean by "and you may need to rework the last order by line as well to get it working". If it possible can you provide me an example.

Comment: oops sorry I didnt see it because I was too rush to answer before my lunch time. It depends to you at how you want to Order your result. Put both queries into sub queries is one of the options.

Comment: @Mark Thank Mark ..This should work.. Since I need to get the results from both tables and then order, could you please confirm, it is enough to use a one "order by" at the end of the query.  .Unfortunately i can not up vote your answer as i am a new member.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to Union both table, then Order the Combined result? then you can put it into one big subquery, then just use one order by will be enough. Its okay, we are here just trying to help you

Comment: @Mark thank you for the reply.. Yes exactly! yes I used a one order but then still giving me the syntax errors . I am doing something wrong.

Comment: this is the new syntax error I am getting now "Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator."

Comment: @Mark ..OMG your edited answer is working ...You are you are a genius.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use union or union all for this in between these two queries as suggested by mark. But you need to know that UNION removes duplicate records (where all columns in the results are the same), UNION ALL does not.

```
 select M.* 

  from zstatistics M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code
  where C.Maths <= @maths
   AND C.Science <= @science
    AND C.English <= @english
    And C.Ict <= @ict
    And C.History <= @history
    And C.Geography <= @geography
    And C.Art <= @Art

UNION

select M.* 
from zsuggestions M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code 
where C.Maths <= @maths
  AND C.Science <= @science
  AND C.English <= @english
  And C.Ict <= @ict
  And C.History <= @history
  And C.Geography <= @geography
  And C.Art <= @Art
```

Or you can directly use UNION ALL if you want query to return duplicate rows :

```
 select M.* 
  from zstatistics M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code
  where C.Maths <= @maths
   AND C.Science <= @science
    AND C.English <= @english
    And C.Ict <= @ict
    And C.History <= @history
    And C.Geography <= @geography
    And C.Art <= @Art

UNION ALL

select M.* 
from zsuggestions M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code 
where C.Maths <= @maths
  AND C.Science <= @science
  AND C.English <= @english
  And C.Ict <= @ict
  And C.History <= @history
  And C.Geography <= @geography
  And C.Art <= @Art
```

Comment: thank you for the reply and I ll try this in few hours. So I add the "order by" part at the end only ? will  it order the both table results?